# Show that the convex set spanned by $P_1,...,P_n$ is the smallest convex set containing those points

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, convex-analysis

This is Theorem $3.2$ from Serg Lang's 'Introduction to Linear Algebra' and Theorem $5.2$ from Lang's 'Linear Algebra'; I was hoping to get some clarification on the proof of the theorem.

Let $P_1,...,P_n$ be elements of a vector space V. Any convex set $S$ which contains $P_1,...,P_n$ also contains all linear combinations $$t_1P_1+...+t_nP_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_iP_i$$
with $0\leq t_i$ for all $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nt_i=1.$

*Pf:*

The proof proceeds nicely, (as usual) by induction. If $n=1$, then $t_1=1$ and clearly the assertion follows.

Now assume the theorem is proved for some $n-1\ge1$; we prove it for $n$. Let $t_1,...,t_n$ be such that $$\sum_{i=1}^nt_i=1$$

If $t_n=1,$ then the assertion follows again trivially from the base case since $t_1=...=t_{n-1}=0$. So assume $t_n\neq1$ so we may write $$t_1P_1+...+t_nP_n=(1-t_n)\left(\frac{t_1}{1-t_n}P_1+...+\frac{t_{n-1}}{1-t_n}P_{n-1}\right)+t_nP_n$$

The author then states the following in the first text: $$\text{Let $s_i=\frac{t_i}{1-t_i}$ for $i=1,...,n-1$}$$
and in the second: $$\text{Let $s_i=\frac{t_n}{1-t_n}$ for $i=1,...,n-1$}$$

then after these statements in each text (which I think are both wrong?), the author concludes $$\text{Then $s_i\geq0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}s_i=1$}$$

I think both of these expressions for $s_i$ are wrong; shouldn't $s_i$ be $$s_i=\frac{t_i}{1-t_n}\text{ for $i=1,...,n-1$}$$ But then, I don't see how $$\frac{t_1}{1-t_n}+...+\frac{t_{n-1}}{1-t_n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{t_i}{1-t_n}=^?1$$

I get the following by the induction hypothesis: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{t_i}{1-t_n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}t_i}{1-t_n}=\frac{1}{1-t_n}$$

But I don't see how this helps me.

Can anyone help me decipher this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the $s_i$; it should indeed be
$$s_i = \frac{t_i}{1 - t_n}.$$
I think what you're missing is that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} t_i$ need not be $1$; it is assumed, as part of the induction step that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i = 1$, and so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} t_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i - t_n = 1 - t_n \implies \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{t_i}{1 - t_n} = 1.$$

Comment: Oh. I thought when Lang says "Assume the theorem is proved for some integer $n-1\geq 1$" he means assume any $n-1$ points in a convex set necessitates that convex set to contain all linear combinations $t_1P_1+...+t_{n-1}P_{n-1}$ with $0\leq t_i$ for all $i$ and $t_1+...+t_{n-1}=1$?

Comment: It's assumed that, given any $P'_1, \ldots, P'_n$, convex $C$ containing these points, and non-negative $t'_1, \ldots, t'_{n-1}$ that sum to $1$, that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} t'_i P'_i \in C.$$ In this case, we have $t'_i = t_i/(1 - t_n)$; it's still a convex combination with $n - 1$ terms.

Comment: oh wow I see now, I can believe I missed that! Thank you!